# Java File access - URI madness

Tags: java, url, uri, filepath

I'm working with IBM OmniFind, with has a fun way of handling file paths. If you've got a path like this:

```
C:\temp\some §$% path\temp - Sho rtcut.lnk
```

It becomes to this sort of "URI" (that's what they call it...):

```
file:///C:/temp/some+%C2%A7%24%25+path/temp+-+Sho+rtcut.lnk
```

This clearly seems to be escaped with URLEncoder.encode. Normally, Java would build this sort of URI from the path above:

```
file:/C:/temp/some%20%C2%A7$%25%20path/temp%20-%20Sho%20rtcut.lnk
file:/C:/temp/some%20§$%25%20path/temp%20-%20Sho%20rtcut.lnk
```

Now I have a really hard time of transforming this sort of URL Encoded Path into something that would work for File handles. This sort of does the trick, although it seems like a very questionable workaround:

```
String path = "file:///C:/temp/some+%C2%A7%24%25+path/temp+-+Sho+rtcut.lnk";
URL url = new URL(path);
path = url.toExternalForm().replaceAll("[+]", "%20");

URI uri = new URI(path);
File file = new File(uri);
System.out.println(file.exists());
```

Is there any safe-ish way of transforming URL escaped file paths to valid URIs in Java?